# Accuracy in assertEquals?

Tags: unit-testing, assert

I have a quick question:

```
/**
* Method a1
*
* @param p1 A parameter
* @param p2 A parameter
* @return The return value
*/

    public double a1(double p1, double p2) {
    return (p1 + p2) / 2;
    }

    @Test
    public void testa1() {
    assertEquals(0, a1(32.56, 45.90), 0.0 );
    }
```

keeps giving me a value very long 39.23000000000000004. How can I reduce the accuracy of this in the assert test bit?

Comment: What programming language is this ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @Hamid R: Did any of the answers provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is the expected value, the second is the actual value, and the third parameter to assertEquals is the acceptable delta.  You can make it `.01` or whatever you need.

So your statement should be something like

`assertEquals(39.23, a1(32.56, 45.90), 0.1 );`

doubles and floats will almost always not be the exact number you think they are.  That is because with 32/64 bits, only so many exact numbers can be represented.  There is always an **infinite** number of numbers that cannot be represented *exactly*.  That's why you need the delta.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly define an AssertAlmostEqual together with a parameter that defines the accuracy (or default argument).

e.g. 
    def AssertAlmostEquals(value1, value2, accuracy = 0.000001):
         assertEquals(abs(value1 - value2) < accuracy)